# Css / JS hide element on collision

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that I am using at the bottom of my clients page. It is an `absolute` positioned image on the bottom left of the screen, inside the footer div.

```
.footer__endrow > .chefBottom {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[image]

This works and looks fine when on the desktop at a normal resolution. However, when the window is made smaller, it starts to collide with the social icons there and goes behind them.

[image]

The viewport it self is still well within range of a normal desktop website when viewing the second image so I can't just hide it when its at tablet or mobile size as the collision would have already hapend.

Is there a way with javascript or css to hide an image when it collides with another element? For example detect if the element touches another one and then hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find your breakpoint of when images collide with social icons using chrome developer tool `inspect element` in responsive mode and then use media query to hide the element at the end of your css file like

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
  .footer__endrow > .chefBottom{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

*Note: Here I have used `480px` as a breakpoint*

Comment: Does this matter where its placed within the CSS? I added it to my page, along with the max width adjustment and it still remains when the screen hits that number as well as exceeding it. I'm probably doing something wrong, answer seems straightforward

Comment: @SBB placed it at the end of your custom css file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it with javascript way, then it is better to solve this way.

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
   var $imgDiv; // assign image div here
   var $socialIconsDiv; // assign social icon div here
   var $imgDivRightOffset = $($imgDiv).offset().left + $("$imgDiv").outerWidth(); //get image right position
   var $socialIconDivLeftOffset = $($socialIconsDiv).offset().left // get social icons left position

   if( $socialIconDivLeftOffset <= (imgDivRightOffset) ){
      $($socialIconDivLeftOffset).hide();// Hide social icons here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can check the position of both the image and see if the position is overlapping if it is over lapping in the if condition you can hide it.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    var imageOne = document.getElementById('firstImage');
    // check for the image which you want overlapping add the condition as per that.
    if (imageTwo.offsetLeft <= imageOne.offsetLeft) {

        //use this command to hide the image.
        imageOne.style.visibility = 'visible';

    }
});
```